# Possible to protect settings menu with an android app?

Tags: android, security

My employer has told me to create an android app to do the following:

The ability to password protect specific submenus in the Settings menu (i.e. specifically Privacy, Applications, and Location & Security).

Is this possible without rooting?

Comment: Is this specific to mobiles provided by your company? If so, you can root them and write app for whatever you want.

Comment: Yes this is specific to my company. It's an internal app for our phones. But we are not allowed to root, is that possible?

Comment: It seems you can do without rooting. I never did anything like this, but this link has an example. http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/02/change-system-screen-brightness-using.html, In this link, brightness was modified,  something like that you may need to do for your submenu items.

Comment: I don't understand how changing the brightness relates to the locking of certain settings menu?

Answer (score 0):

Not without Root-Access :-)
And if you require Root-Access many Users will not have the possibility to use the App. It may also occure that this App will not be allowed to the Marketplace.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure? My employer is shouting at me because he said he heard it from a friend that it's possible without rooting. We don't care about the Marketplace because this is an internal company app.

Comment: yes i am, but i am a human afterall, maybe it is possible. But Reason, Logic and Experience speaks against it.
Imagine some guy installing an app from the marketplace, which locks the settings, acts like a virus. And the Android Marketplace failed to find this app in their Security-Check.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html
if there is ever a option to do it, here you should find it. For my part, i cannot find it :-)